# tensorflow graph error when trying to generate data in transfer learning

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use transfer learning on the pretrained inception model, so I created a class for feature extraction from the model:

```
from prototype import Dataset, VideoStreamHandler
import numpy
import random
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from scipy.misc import imresize
import time


class Extractor(Dataset.Dataset):
    """
    """

    def __init__(self, path_to_data, seq_len, base_model, image_shape=(299, 299, 3)):
        super().__init__(path_to_data, seq_len, input_shape=image_shape)
        self._extractor = base_model

    def extract_features(self, batch_size):
        """
        passes the data through the base model to get the feature map to later train on
        :return: feature map
        """
        class_one_hot = self.one_hot_encode()  # get the one hot for the classes
        data = self.clean_data(self.get_data(), self._input_shape[0])

        print("Processing {} videos".format(len(self.get_data())))
        transfer_maps, labels = [], []
        rand = random.SystemRandom()

        while True:
            for _ in range(batch_size):
                row = rand.choice(data)

                sequence = self.get_frames(row[0])

                if len(sequence) > self._input_shape[0]:
                    sequence = self.rescale_frame_list(sequence, self._input_shape[0])

                print("{} video processing is complete".format(row[0].split('\\')[-1]))

                features = []
                for frame in sequence:
                    frame_arr = image.img_to_array(frame)  # turn image to numpy array
                    frame_arr = numpy.expand_dims(frame_arr, axis=0)
                    frame_arr = preprocess_input(frame_arr)
                    features.append(self._extractor.predict(frame_arr))

                transfer_maps.append(features)
                labels.append(class_one_hot[row[1]])

            yield numpy.array(transfer_maps), numpy.array(labels)

    def get_frames(self, pth):
        """
        :type: string
        :param pth: path to the specific file from which we take the frames

        :return: the frames in the file
        """
        f_queue = VideoStreamHandler.VideoStream(pth)  # This object opens a thread that reads frames with opencv
        # capture independently from the frame processing to prevent i/o delay and speed up processing
        f_queue.start()
        time.sleep(1.0)  # wait a moment so the thread could start reading frames
        sequence = []

        while f_queue.isnt_empty():
            frame = f_queue.read()
            # resize is used to keep all frames from all videos the same size
            frame = imresize(frame, (self._input_shape[1], self._input_shape[2]))

            sequence.append(frame)

        f_queue.close()  # close the thread
        return sequence
```

Then, I attempt to train a new model with keras's fit_generator:

```
    my_model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, verbose=1, workers=4)
```

However, I get this error:

> Blockquote
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Aviad Lazar/Desktop/project/prototype/transfer_learning.py", line 41, in 
>       main()
>     File "C:/Users/Aviad Lazar/Desktop/project/prototype/transfer_learning.py", line 34, in main
>       my_model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, verbose=1, workers=4)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1315, in fit_generator
>       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2194, in fit_generator
>       generator_output = next(output_generator)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 793, in get
>       six.reraise(value.**class**, value, value.**traceback**)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
>       raise value
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 658, in _data_generator_task
>       generator_output = next(self._generator)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\prototype\FeatureExtractor.py", line 48, in extract_features
>       features.append(self._extractor.predict(frame_arr))
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1832, in predict
>       self._make_predict_function()
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1031, in _make_predict_function
>       **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2506, in function
>       return Function(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2449, in **init**
>       with tf.control_dependencies(self.outputs):
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4863, in control_dependencies
>       return get_default_graph().control_dependencies(control_inputs)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4481, in control_dependencies
>       c = self.as_graph_element(c)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3478, in as_graph_element
>       return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
>     File "C:\Users\Aviad Lazar\Desktop\project\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3557, in _as_graph_element_locked
>       raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
>   ValueError: Tensor Tensor("global_average_pooling2d_1/Mean:0", shape=(?, 2048), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with fit_generator and not the model? Does `my_model.fit()` work without throwing an error?

Comment: Yes, I switched to fit a few days ago and it has been working fine.